# Bolding a Display Name in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to show the Display Name here in BOLD. This is in WPF.

}

```
string fDisplayName;
[Persistent("DISPLAY_NAME")]
public string DisplayName
{
    get { return fDisplayName; }
    set { SetPropertyValue<string>("DisplayName", ref fDisplayName, value); }
}
```

using AppointmentLabel = DevExpress.Xpf.Scheduler.AppointmentLabel;
using Resource = DevExpress.XtraScheduler.Resource;

Comment: ASP.Net is the exact opposite of WPF.

Comment: In your xaml, use FontWeight="Bold"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code fragment you provided does not show anything.
Persistence is related to storage, not display.
BOLD and other formatting options apply at the time string actually gets displayed.